# How to Access Output Parameters from Azure ARM in next Tasks?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, release

I am writing ARM scripts for my Azure infra. I have sample output variable in my ARM

```
"OutputVariables": [{
    "name" : "MY_OUTPUTVARIABLE_1",
    "description" : "This is the description of my output variable."
}, 
{
    "name" : "MY_OUTPUTVARIABLE_2",
    "description" : "Description can contains markdown [vsts-tasks](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-tasks)"
}]
```

I want to access these ARM output variables in the next task of my VSTS release tasks.

I am not able to access variable MY_OUTPUTVARIABLE_1.

Please suggest how to use ARM output variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2018/05/10/parsing-your-arm-template-output-in-vsts-pipelines/) shows you how to parse the output variables in VSTS. You need to make sure you define them as outputs of the task so VSTS knows what to look for. This can be found in the Output Variables section at the bottom of the task.

If it isn't initialised in the pipeline it can't be found. Also it's worth noting the ARM template you have provided doesn't actually set a value for the parameter. [The ARM documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-templates-outputs) shows the correct way of setting output variables.

```
"outputs": {
"resourceID": {
  "type": "string",
  "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIPAddresses_name'))]"
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.